# Overlapping layout for a form on a webpage

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a form looking like that:

[image: Design project]

I tried with a table embedding another two tables, one with 5 rows and the other with 6 rows, and tried to arrange it with CSS, but somehow it doesn't seem to work out. I'm looking for a solution to correct my design or for completely another (with div's?). Here my code:

```
<td style="display: table-cell; text-align: right; height: 80%;">
    <table style="display: table-cell; text-align: right; height: 80%;">
    <tr>  
    <td width="180" align="right">
        <tech:label key="tolerancesurecarts.input.label.palier1" 
                     labelfor="inputPalier1" />
    </td>
    <td width="180" >
        <tech:text property="inputPalier1" 
                    mode="EEEE" maxlength="8" size="9"/>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="180" align="right">
        <tech:label key="tolerancesurecarts.input.label.palier2" 
                     labelfor="inputPalier2" />
    </td>
    <td width="180" >
        <tech:text property="inputPalier2" 
                    mode="EEEE" maxlength="8" size="9"/>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>  
    <td width="180" align="right">
        <tech:label key="tolerancesurecarts.input.label.palier3" 
                     labelfor="inputPalier3" />
    </td>
    <td width="180" >
        <tech:text property="inputPalier3" 
                    mode="EEEE" maxlength="8" size="9"/>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="180" align="right">
        <tech:label key="tolerancesurecarts.input.label.palier4" 
                     labelfor="inputPalier4" />
    </td>
    <td width="180" >
        <tech:text property="inputPalier4" 
                    mode="EEEE" maxlength="8" size="9"/>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="180" align="right">
        <tech:label key="tolerancesurecarts.input.label.palier5" 
                     labelfor="inputPalier5" />
    </td>
    <td width="180" >
        <tech:text property="inputPalier5" 
                    mode="EEEE" maxlength="8" size="9"/>
    </td>
</tr>

    </table>
</td>
<td style="text-align: left;">
    <table style="text-align: left;">
        <tr>
            <td><div style="background-color: #CDFFAA; height: 100%;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div style="background-color: #FFFF99; height: 100%;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div style="background-color: #FFDC77; height: 100%;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div style="background-color: #FFBA44; height: 100%;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div style="background-color: #F07300; height: 100%;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div style="background-color: #A00000; height: 100%;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```

I tried some different variations, using various `display` css attributes on my first table, `height` css attributes on the cells, and so on, to no avail. Any idea?

Comment: Share your code with demo in Jsfiddle,.

Comment: Is this the way you are getting ressult? https://jsfiddle.net/se8ssbzm/

Comment: @SandeepKushwah: No, it's not looking like that.  It's hard to obtain a demo, because of the server-side tags inside of the code...

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy please check this. I have updated the code - https://jsfiddle.net/se8ssbzm/1/

Comment: If you find it right I will do it better.

Comment: More like that https://jsfiddle.net/sua15zok/ except the two tables are the same height. What I get in jsfiddle is actually near what I would like to get...

Comment: Yeah, it's like you show it in your second proposition

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy : But in the picture you have pasted in the diagram is also having the diferrent height of the tables.. What I am getting now is you want your both(textbox and color) the columns of same height right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89383/discussion-between-sandeep-kushwah-and-alexis-dufrenoy).

Comment: maybe need to reset input CSS UA

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy :  Here is the solution https://jsfiddle.net/sua15zok/2/  
Please check, if its okay I will post it as solution

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not at all what I need, as I said on the chat. I need to sort of squeeze the left table. The one with the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for https://jsfiddle.net/sua15zok/3/ . Please specify if any corrections `in css` required. I will do it and update the required UI.

Comment: Yeah, I've done something like that, finally. Using a fixed height for the cells in the color table.